# Add public getter in Java to protected field in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am doing some refactoring to a base class in Kotlin. It looks like the following:

```kotlin
abstract class Base constructor (protected val prop: Int) {
   //...
}
```

I have an implementation in Java that wants to expose `prop` via a public getter. Is this possible?

```java
public class Impl extends Base {
    public Int getProp() {
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Causes an error like the following:

```
Impl.java:269: error: getProp() in Impl cannot override getProp() in Base
    public Int getProp() {
                ^
  overridden method is final
```

Comment: Do you have a `getProp()` method in `Base` that has permissions not `public`?

Comment: Yup. See the constructor: `protected val prop: Int`.

Comment: Can you modify the Kotlin code?  It seems like `protected open val prop: Int` might suffice.

Comment: I can. If you add that as your answer. I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to make `getProp` overridable, which you can do just by writing

```
protected open val prop: Int
```

in the Kotlin code.